# Fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 on new laptop is suffering poor performance

Tags: system-installation

I have Ubuntu on multiple laptops with no problems regarding performance, however the performance with Ubuntu on my new laptop is not great.  I feel like my hardware is not being utilized.

Here are the specs:

- [Gateway NE71B series](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1025565822.pdf)
- 4GB DDR3 Memory
- 500GB HDD
- AMD Radeon HD 7310

After installing Ubuntu 13.04, I opened Firefox to view Youtube and it worked fine. However, when I opened the video in full view, the video slowed and lagged. Once I closed full view, it returned to normal speed. The internet connection works on other laptops. Also the system crashes under high software load; for example: a few windows opened, like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/), Software Centre, and home folder.

Is this due to the AMD chipsets like the dual core E1-1200?

I've also found that the mouse is slow as well.

This is a new install, so no virus yet.  What can I do to boost performance?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 in such specs and it works fine. Make sure you've done a full installation without errors and why not try the 64bit version of Ubuntu

Comment: Its all in the CPU. The CPU 64BIT is at near 100% usage playing a youtube video. I installed XUBUNTU to free up some usage and got better result with flash Its not a fix though. This is why I wonder can I do anything to fix drivers. I am uncertain. System monitor is fine except for CPU.